# Is it possible to create a decorator inside a class?

Tags: python, exception, python-decorators, keyboardinterrupt

Or maybe you can think of an alternative solution to what I'm trying to do. Basically I have a class with a bunch of functions that I want to wrap in try/except blocks to intercept the *KeyboardInterrupt* error as I have a function that tidily cleans up each of my functions.

Instead of putting huge try catch blocks in each function I figured I could create a decorator to do that, but I'm running into some issues. So far I have something like this

```
class MyClass:
    def catch_interrupt(self, func):
        def catcher():
            try:
                func()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.End()
        return catcher

    @catch_interrupt
    def my_func(self):
        # Start a long process that might need to be interrupted

    def End(self):
        # Cleans up things
        sys.exit()
```

The issue when I run this is that I get the error

```
TypeError: catch_interrupt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is this even possible? Is there a better way or should I really just put try/except blocks around each functions innards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to create a decorator inside a class, but your implementation is faulty:

First of all, `catch_interrupt()` can't take `self`.

```
@catch_interrupt
def my_func(self):
    # Start a long process that might need to be interrupted
```

is equivalent to

```
def my_func(self):
    # Start a long process that might need to be interrupted
my_func = catch_interrupt(my_func)
```

Obviously this doesn't allow `self`.

Secondly, your inner wrapper function that you return from the decorator needs to at least take `self` as an argument and pass it on to `func`, as the functions you will be decorating expect `self` as their first arguments.

You may also want to call your internal decorator `_catch_interrupt` to hint that it's meant for internal usage. That won't prevent anyone from calling it, but it's good practice given the behavior will be incorrect if called on an instance of the class (e.g. `MyClass().catch_interrupt()` will attempt to decorate the `MyClass` instance itself, which you probably don't want).

---

My suggestion, however, would be to implement a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) instead and have it perform your cleanup. That is more Pythonic for the cases where you're just enclosing a group of statements, and if you implement it right you can actually use it as a decorator too.

Comment: Without passing in self how would I call my End() function?

Comment: @ProgrammerUnextraordinair Implement the behavior in a context manager instead, they have a method for automatic cleanup when context is left and it even takes parameters indicating whether or not the exit was due to successful completion or a raised exception.

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want to stick with your current decorator, then the fact that `catcher()` needs to take `self` as its first argument anyway means you'll still have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use decorators inside a class in the nature you propose. I think that this would be counter-intuitive to the purpose of decorators themselves (a hack, so to say).

What is wrong with a try-except block? You already put all the cleanup code in a function so are adhering to the DRY principle. A decorator and/or wrapper would only limit the flexibility of your error handling, by fixing that the try-except statement wraps your entire function(s), without providing any real added benefit.